# Chrome Bluetooth Low Energy API - Cross-Platform Support

Tags: macos, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I accessed the [Chrome BLE API page](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetoothLowEnergy) (5/7/2016). there seem to be conflicting information messages (see image below). Does this work on Chrome OS only, or OS X and Windows also?

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

I tried the demo application ([demo BLE API](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/bluetooth-samples/device-info-demo)) on Windows 10. It was able to see **paired** devices, but **not** unpaired devices. I got an error message: `Battery device not supported on this platform`. I'm not sure if this is because of the test vector I used ([LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-explorer-bluetooth/id557428110?mt=8)), or another issue.

*System:*

- Windows 10 64 bit
- Surface Pro 3

[image: Chrome API Page]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy` API works only for paired devices on Windows as it still uses (at that time) Windows 8 APIs to retrieve paired devices only: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/08c9d69b0c0d625d2ce38e3d8402f36e1226f0fc/device/bluetooth/bluetooth_low_energy_win.h#117

For info, the Web Bluetooth team plans to support Windows 10 as much as feasible: https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/gh-pages/implementation-status.md#chrome

Comment: Very interesting. I was excited to see the Windows support, but based on what I am reading there is only discovery for paired devices and no read/write for GATT. That would explain the failed read requests.

Just to make sure I understand, the `chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy` API and the Web Bluetooth API are using the **same** code?

Comment: They are using the same code under the hood for now. This means all the work the Web Bluetooth team is doing to improve cross-platform support will benefit to the `chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy` API eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through your given documentation wherein you referenced the use of `navigator.bluetooth`, [Interact with BLE devices on the Web](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web?hl=en) also states that:

> Web Bluetooth API is **at the time of writing partially implemented in Chrome OS and Chrome Dev** for Android behind an experimental flag.

Hence, you got **undefined** as a return value.

Functionalities were provided by Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) through key/value pairs provided by the [Generic Attribute Profile (GATT)](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#generic-attribute-profile).

Comment: It appears that the Web Bluetooth API is different from the Chrome API Bluetooth specification. Hence `navigator.bluetooth` was the incorrect way to check. I am focusing on the Chrome API specifically.